# how to write a directive for angularjs that replaces dom elements without using ng-transclude?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wish to write a directive that basically transforms this:

```
<g:text>Hello There</g:text>

to

<svg class="gx-text"><text>Hello There</text></svg>
```

so that in the dom, the `<g:text>` element has been completely replaced by the `<svg>` element

I don't want to use ng-transclude as I found that it added a bunch of other elements to the dom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('gText', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function(tElement, attrs) {
            tElement.replaceWith('<svg class="gx-text"><text>'
                + tElement.text() + '</text></svg>');
        }
    }
});
```

​[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/jwzAV/)