# how to write a directive for angularjs that replaces the dom element but keeps bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

following on from this question:
[how to write a directive for angularjs that replaces dom elements without using ng-transclude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872402/how-to-write-a-directive-for-angularjs-that-replaces-dom-elements-without-using/13873284#13873284)

I wish to write a directive that changes the dom element but then retains all the attributes and bindings.

```
<g:text x={{myX}} y={{myY}} font-size=10>Hello There</g:text>
```

to

```
<text x={{myX}} y={{myY}} font-size=10>Hello There</text>
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the same logic and copy the attributes during the compile:

```
 app.directive('gText', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
            var attrs = tElement[0].attributes;
            tElement.replaceWith('<text>' + tElement.text() + '</text>');            
            for (var i=0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
                tElement.attr(attrs.item(i).nodeName, attrs.item(i).nodeValue);               
            }
        }
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YWfSF/

Answer (score 8):

To the best of my knowledge, Angular will port attributes to the new element automatically. No need to iterate over them all yourself.

In your case, you would also need to transclude the content if you want to keep it.

```
app.directive('myText', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: '<text ng-transclude></text>'
    }
});
```

This is from the top of my memory, but I believe something similar to this would do the trick. Every attribute of the original element will be ported to the new element, and the element's content will be transcluded too. Binds preserved and all.

Comment: I believe you meant "replace"

Comment: Also need the `transclude: true` attribute

Comment: @diegovilar, your directive is an attribute directive (because you didn't specify `restrict`), so it wouldn't match the original question's request for an element (`<g:text>`). Your directive would have to be used like this `<text my-text ...` instead

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. I wish somebody who understands this answer would be so kind as to update the answer to take the comments into account, since it seems that this answer isn't good to go by itself. I would greatly prefer it over the selected answer, though, if it works, since this solution looks way simpler.

Comment: A quick update on @Daryn's comment for anyone new to Angular reading this: while this was correct back in '13 (v1.2), as of v1.3 the default is `restrict: 'EA'`. So `restrict` could be omitted from the Directive Definition Object and this answer would still work as expected.

Comment: In response to Jason Swett I have provided an updated answer

Answer (score 0):

(In response to Jason Swett request for an update)

this works in Angular 1.4.9 (and prob earlier too)

```
return {
      restrict: 'E', // optional
      replace: true, // optional
      template: '<span data-ng-transclude></span>',
      transclude: true,
      link: function (scope, el, attrs) .........
}
```

A great article on this is at ...

https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/angularjs-transclusion-part-1/